# Wordpress plugin to display tabular overview of complete archive

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a page on my Wordpress blog that contains a tabular overview of *all* my posts over time. Here are the requirements I'm looking for:

**Must have**

- Tabular overview in reverse chronological order;
- Column with post date;
- Column with post title (title must be a link to the post);
- Column with categories;
- Plays well with existing themes (I currently use "Sparkling");
- Can be shown as a / on a static page;

**Should have**

- Stable across updates of Wordpress and Themes (i.e. if I'd customize a theme I'd be afraid updating said theme would undo any changes...);

**Nice to have**

- Client side sorting (e.g. by clicking the headers);
- Categories as links;
- Support for additional columns (e.g. tags, author, etc);

I'm not sure, but I *think* I'm looking for a plugin. But perhaps I'm mistaken and this is something that would be a feature of a *theme*?

I've [searched](https://www.google.nl/search?q=wordpress+show+tabular+archive) but [the top result](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-archive-data-in-a-sortable-table-format) was from *7 years ago* and closed. I've tried a few searches for plugins inside Wordpress itself but found nothing fitting my requirements so far.

In the past I had a hand-crafted theme that had a hand-crafted page template to do this, but I wanted to move to a new look, decided to use an existing theme. I guess I could port my template to my new theme but (a) don't feel my code is all that great (I'm no PHP dev) and (b) would be afraid that I'd loose my customization when I'd update the theme.

What would you recommend?